# Alternative methods to add multiple user inputs to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add multiple key-value pairs from user inputs to a dictionary. This is what I have now:

```
user = {}
counter = 1
for i in range(4):
    letter, number = input('Pair {}: '.format(counter)).split()
    user[letter] = int(number)
    counter += 1
```

Output:

```
user = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

It works but I want to know if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: questions about improving code which already works should actually asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. You can avoid manually incrementing `counter` by using `range(1, 5)`:

```
user = {}
for counter in range(1, 5):
    letter, number = input('Pair {}: '.format(counter)).split()
    user[letter] = int(number)
```

One-liner:

```
user = {letter: int(number) for letter, number in
        (input('Pair {}: '.format(counter)).split() for counter in range(1, 5))}
```

The one-liner is pretty dense and spreads over two physical lines. Therefore, the loop seems easier to read.

Comment: Thanks `+1` I agree that one-liner is pretty dense here, and loop approach seems easier to read. Just for curiosity I asked ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking if it's possible for a dictionary comprehension but it's harder to read than I thought.